# Remove the last few capital letters on R

Tags: r, string

I was wondering how I could remove the last few capital letters and symbol "/" of each observation string in R? For example, if I have data like

```
    PlayerFirstLastNameABC
    PlayerNameAB/CDF
    PlayerFirstMN
    PlayerLastNameABC/RS
```

and so on, how do I get it to return to me:

```
    PlayerFirstLastName
    PlayerName
    PlayerFirst
    PlayerLastName
```

where the last letter of the string is always a lower case letter? i.e. Remove all end of strings until you hit a lower case letter. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` from `base R` to match one or more (`+`) upper case letters along with `/` till the end (`$`) of the string and replace with blank (`""`)

```
sub("[A-Z/]+$", "", v1)
#[1] "PlayerFirstLastName" "PlayerName"         
#[3] "PlayerFirst"         "PlayerLastName"
```

---

Or using `trimws`

```
trimws(v1, whitespace = "[A-Z/]+", which = "right")
#[1] "PlayerFirstLastName" "PlayerName"       
#[3]   "PlayerFirst"         "PlayerLastName"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("PlayerFirstLastNameABC", "PlayerNameAB/CDF", "PlayerFirstMN", 
"PlayerLastNameABC/RS")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture everything until upper case letters and `/` at the end of the string.

```
sub('(.*?)[/A-Z]+$', '\\1', x)
#[1] "PlayerFirstLastName" "PlayerName"  "PlayerFirst"  "PlayerLastName"
```